# Javascript shows when stored in the database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security

I am storing "<script>alert("Hello")</script>" in the database and when i try to display the content in a Label it shows alert in the web page how can I solve this.

Comment: "<script>alert("Hello")</script>"

Comment: The content I am storing in the database should be displayed as it is in the label instead it displays an alert in the webpage how can it be displayed in the label. Please understand the question before giving negative marks

Comment: Please ensure you understand https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet and why your method of encoding needs to be different, depending on where in your output you print your potentially malicious string.

Answer (score 3):

(1) Don't use a label, use a `Literal` control and set the mode to "Encode", so your  tags will be HTML encoded: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx.

Or

(2). Say: `label.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(stringFromDataBase);`

(3): Edit: I should also mention, you can use the code nugget: <%: which will html encode the text. It's the same as <%=, except, the output is HTML encoded. Very handy. Example: `Welcome: <%: UserName %>`

Comment: This is not just a good idea because it fixes the OP's problem, but it also is a security issue to just throw raw HTML to the browser. @Matthew Paul : Do yourself a favor and read up on "Cross Site Scripting" and "Cross Site Request Forgery" hacks. Your existing solution is vulnerable to them.

Comment: +1. It's a great, great pity that ASP.NET made the Text` property escape by default on *some* but not all controls.